# Using powershell to perform action on WPF listbox with multiple indices

Tags: wpf, powershell

I am trying to update an old powershell script. It currently has a GUI built in the script, and the updated GUI was built with WPF, but still is a powershell script. It mostly works, but the problem I am having is this: The script's purpose is to move folders from a source to a fixed destination. The user selects the folder and then chooses which files to move, and the "load files" button should update with the count and total size of files. The old script does this correctly, however, the new script will not. With a PS built GUI, I can use "SelectedIndices"; with the WPF built GUI, I can only use "SelectedIndex", and have yet to find a workaround so the button will properly update. Currently it keeps the size of the first selected item. Does anyone know a solution to this? I have been searching and using trial-and-error all week, with no success. I am adding the relevant pieces of code and result photos below. Edited to provide full sample

```
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework  # WPF assemblies
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms   # .NET assemblies

if (-not $env:dataFolder) {
   $env:dataFolder =  "D:"
}
$addModulePath = Join-Path -Path $env:dataFolder -ChildPath "Libraries\modules"
if (-not $env:PSModulePath.Contains($addModulePath)) {
   $env:PSModulePath = $addModulePath + ";" + $env:PSModulePath
}

$Global:mainFolder = 'D:\Database\PackageFiles'
$Global:appFolder = "$env:dataFolder\Tools\databaseUpdateTool"
$Global:Icon = "$env:dataFolder\Libraries\icons\redAppLogo.ico"
# Generic Globals - - verify if there will be any changes
$Global:untouchablePackages = @("package names that cannot be deleted show here as an array")

#___ Class Definitions ___


class Package {
   [String]$name = $null
   [String]$fullName = $null
   [int64]$size = 0
   [String]$pickList = $null

#Constructors

# Return and null Structure
   Package() {}

   Package($folder) {
      $theSize = getFolderSize $folder.fullName
      $this.name = $folder.name
      $this.size = $theSize
      $this.fullName = $folder.fullName
      $this.pickList = ($theSize / 1gb).ToString('0.00').padleft(9) + ' GB  ' + $folder.name
   }

# Takes a package, returns a duplicate
   [Package]duplicate($newPath) {
      $newPackage = [Package]::New()
      $newPackage.name = $this.name
      $newPackage.size = $this.size
      $newPackage.pickList = $this.pickList
      $newPackage.fullName = $this.fullName
         if ($newPackage -ne $null) {
            $newPackage.fullName = (Join-Path -Path $newPath -ChildPath $this.name)
         }
      return $newPackage
   }
}


#___ Functions ___

function getArraySize ($anObject) {
   if ($anObject) {
      if ($anObject -is [System.Array]) {
         $theSize = $anObject.count
      } else {
         $theSize = 1
      }
   } else {
      $theSize = 0
   }
   return [int]$theSize
}


function getFolderSize {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [parameter(position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [string] $aFolder
   )

   $aList = Get-ChildItem -force $aFolder
   $size = 0
   foreach ($member in $aList) {
      if ($member.gettype().name -eq 'FileInfo') {
         $size = $size + $member.length
      } else {
         $size = $size + (getFolderSize $member.fullname)
      }
   }
   return $size
}


# copyPackageFolder allows users to copy location packages into the D: drive

function copyPackageFolder {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [parameter(position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] $target
   )

   try {
      $results1 = Copy-Item -Path $target.fullName -Destination $Global:removeFolder -Recurse 
      $results1
      $returnValue = $results1 -eq $null
   } catch {
      $returnValue = $false
   }
   return $returnValue
}


# removePackageFolder is similar to copyPackageFolder, with a Remove-Item instead of Copy-Item
function removePackageFolder {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [parameter(position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] $removePackage
   )

   try {
     Remove-Item -LiteralPath $removePackage.fullName  -Recurse -Force 
      $returnValue = $true
   } catch {
      $returnValue = $false
   }
   return $returnValue
}


function getPickListFromFolder {
# Extracts names and sizes of top-level directories and returns a list
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
          [parameter(position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string] $aFolder
   )

   $folderList = Get-ChildItem $aFolder
   $myFolderList = @()
   foreach($folder in ($folderList | sort name)) {
      if ($folder.gettype().name -eq 'DirectoryInfo') {
         $theSize = getFolderSize $folder.fullname
         $folderObject = [Package]::New($folder)

         if (-not $untouchablePackages.contains($folderObject.name)) {
            $myFolderList += $folderObject
         }
      }
   }
   if ($myFolderList.count -gt 0) {
      return ,($myFolderList)
   } else {
      return $null
   }
}


function getFolderName {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [parameter(position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [string]$windowText,
      [parameter(position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$false)] [string]$defaultFolder
   )
#
   [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
   $openFolderDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.folderBrowserDialog
   if ($defaultFolder) {$openFolderDialog.SelectedPath = $defaultFolder}
   if ($windowText)  {
      $openFolderDialog.Description = $windowText
   } else {
      $openFolderDialog.Description = 'Please select a folder'
   }
   $openFolderDialog.RootFolder = 'MyComputer'
   $buttonAnswer = $openFolderDialog.ShowDialog()

   if ($buttonAnswer -match 'ok') {
      return $openFolderDialog.SelectedPath
   } else {
      return $null
   }
}


function loadUpPackages {
# This is the function that executes when the Load button is clicked
# First it checks if a folder with the same name exists in the destination folder
#    (if so, it prompts the user if they want to replace it)
# Then it executes the copyPackageFolder function
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [parameter(position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [Package]$loadPackage
   )

   BEGIN { }

     PROCESS {
      if ($Global:removeObjList) {
         $conflictingPackage = $Global:removeObjList | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $loadPackage.name }
      } else {
         $conflictingPackage = $null
      }

      if ($conflictingPackage) {
         switch ([System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("The destination already contains a folder named " + $loadPackage.name + " - would you like to replace it?","databaseUpdateTool",'YesNo','None')) {
            'Yes' {
               if (removePackageFolder $conflictingPackage) {
                  $GLOBAL:removeListBox.Items.Remove($conflictingPackage.pickList)
                  $Global:removeObjList = $Global:removeObjList | Where-Object { $_.name -ne $loadPackage.name }
                  if (copyPackageFolder $loadPackage) {
                     $duplicatePackage = $loadPackage.duplicate($GLOBAL:removeFolder)

                     switch (getArraySize $Global:removeObjList) {
                        0       {$Global:removeObjList = $duplicatePackage }
                        1       {$Global:removeObjList = ($Global:removeObjList, $duplicatePackage)}
                        Default {$Global:removeObjList += $duplicatePackage}
                     }
                     $Global:removeListBox.Items.add($duplicatePackage.pickList)
                  } else {
                     $message = ("Unable to load package $loadPackage.name", 'Please try again')
                     $title = 'Load error message'
                     $buttons = [system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons]::OK
                     $results = [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show($message, $title, $buttons)
                  }
               } else {
                  $message = ("Unable to remove package $loadPackage.name", 'Please try again')
                  $title = 'Remove error message'
                  $buttons = [system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons]::OK
                  $results = [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show($message, $title, $buttons)
               }
            }

            'No' {}
            default {}
         }
      } else {
         if (copyPackageFolder $loadPackage) {
            $newPackage = $loadPackage.duplicate($GLOBAL:removeFolder)

            switch (getArraySize $Global:removeObjList) {
               0       {$Global:removeObjList = $newPackage }
               1       {$Global:removeObjList = ($Global:removeObjList, $newPackage)}
               Default {$Global:removeObjList += $newPackage}
            }

            $Global:removeListBox.items.add($newPackage.pickList)
         } else {
            $message = ("Unable to load package $loadPackage.name", 'Please try again')
            $title = 'Load error message'
            $buttons = [system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons]::OK
            $results = [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show($message, $title, $buttons)
         }
      }
   }

   END {
      $loadListBox.Clear()
      if ($Global:removeObjList -eq $null) { $Global:removeObjList = @() }
   }
}


function removePickList {
   # Function output must be explicitly declared as an array - ",( <output here> )"
   $Global:removeObjList = getPickListFromFolder $Global:removeFolder

   if ($Global:removeObjList -ne $null) {
      foreach ($item in $Global:removeObjList.pickList) {
         $theIndex = $GLOBAL:removeListBox.Items.Add($item)
      }
   }
}


function removePackages {
   [CmdletBinding()]
   param (
      [parameter(position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] $removePackage
   )

   BEGIN {
   }

   PROCESS {
      if (removePackageFolder $removePackage) {
         $GLOBAL:removeListBox.Items.Remove($removePackage.pickList)
         $GLOBAL:removeObjList = $GLOBAL:removeObjList | Where { $_ -ne $removePackage }
      } else {
         $packageName = $removePackage.name
         $message = ("Unable to remove package $packageName - Please try again")
         $title = 'Remove error message'
         $buttons = [system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons]::OK
         $results = [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show($message, $title, $buttons)
      }
   }

   END {
      if ($Global:removeObjList -eq $null) { $Global:removeObjList = @() }
   }
}


#___ GUI Functions ___

function getXAMLgui {
#  Read in and process the XAML GUI file. 
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)] [string] $xamlName = $null
    )

    $xamlPath = Join-Path -Path $env:dataFolder -ChildPath "Libraries"
    $xamlFile = Join-Path -Path $xamlPath -ChildPath $xamlName

    $xamlData = New-Object xml
    $xamlData.Load($xamlFile)
    $xamlNodeReader = [System.Xml.XmlNodeReader]::new($xamlData)
    $form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlNodeReader)
        
    return $form
}

function loadBrowseButtonClick{
   $loadPackagesFolder = getFolderName 'Select top level folder containing packages'
   if ($loadPackagesFolder -ne $null) {
      $loadPFtextBox.Text = $loadPackagesFolder
      $Global:loadObjList = getPickListFromFolder $loadPackagesFolder
      $loadListBox.Items.Clear()
      if ($Global:loadObjList -ne $null) {
         foreach ($item in $Global:loadObjList.pickList) {
            $theIndex = $Global:loadListBox.Items.Add($item)
         }
      }
      $loadButton.Content = "load 0 packages (0 GB)"
   }
}

function loadButtonClick{
   $loadMsgBoxTitle = 'Load Packages Message'
   $loadMsgBoxMessage = "Proceed with loading $Global:loadSize GB of data?"
   $loadMsgBoxButtons = [system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons]::YESNO
   $results = [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show($loadMsgBoxMessage, $loadMsgBoxTitle, $loadMsgBoxButtons)
   switch ($results) {
      'Yes' {
      $Global:loadObjList[$Global:loadSelection] | loadUpPackages
      }
   }
}


function loadSelectionChange{
   $Global:loadSelection = $loadListBox.SelectedIndex
   if ($Global:loadSelection -gt 0) {
      switch (getArraySize $Global:loadObjList) {
         0 {
            $Global:loadSize = 0
            $numberOfPackages = 0
            $loadButton.Content = "Load $numberOfPackages packages ($Global:loadSize GB)"
            $loadButton.IsEnabled = $false
            break
         }

         1 {
            $Global:loadSize = ($Global:loadObjList.size / 1gb).ToString('0.00')
            $numberOfPackages = 1
            $loadButton.Content = "Load $numberOfPackages packages ($Global:loadSize GB)"

            if ($Global:freeSpace -lt $Global:loadSize) {
               $loadButton.IsEnabled = $false
            } else {
               $loadButton.IsEnabled = $true
            }
            break
         }

         default {
            $Global:loadSize = (($Global:loadObjList[$Global:loadSelection].size | Measure-Object -Sum).sum / 1gb).ToString('0.00')
            $numberOfPackages = $loadListBox.SelectedItems.Count
            $loadButton.Content = "Load $numberOfPackages packages ($Global:loadSize GB)"

            if ($Global:freeSpace -lt $Global:loadSize) {
               $loadButton.IsEnabled = $false
            } else {
               $loadButton.IsEnabled = $true
            }
          
         }
      }
      $Global:removeListBox.Clear()
   } else {
      $Global:loadSize = 0
      $numberOfPackages = 0
      $loadButton.Content = "Load $numberOfPackages packages ($Global:loadSize GB)"
      $loadButton.IsEnabled = $false
   }
}

function removeButtonClick{
   $removeMsgBoxTitle = 'Remove Packages Message'
   $removeMsgBoxMessage = "Proceed with removal of $Global:removeSize GB of data?"
   $removeMsgBoxButtons = [system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons]::OKCancel
   $results = [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show($removeMsgBoxMessage, $removeMsgBoxTitle, $removeMsgBoxButtons)
   switch ($results) {
      'OK' {
         $Global:removeObjList[$Global:removeSelection] | removePackages
      }
   }
}


function removeSelectionChange{
   $Global:removeSelection = $GLOBAL:removeListBox.SelectedItems
   if ($Global:removeSelection.count -gt 0) {
      switch (getArraySize $Global:removeObjList) {
         0 {
            $Global:removeSize = 0
            $numberOfPackages = 0
            $removeButton.Text = "Remove $numberOfPackages packages ($Global:removeSize GB)"
            $removeButton.IsEnabled = $false
            break
         }

         1 {
            $Global:removeSize = ($Global:removeObjList.size / 1gb).ToString('0.00')
            $numberOfPackages = 1
            $removeButton.Text = "Remove $numberOfPackages packages ($Global:removeSize GB)"
            $removeButton.IsEnabled = $true
            break
         }

         default {
            $Global:removeSize = (($Global:removeObjList[$Global:removeSelection].size | Measure-Object -Sum).sum / 1gb).ToString('0.00')
            $numberOfPackages = $GLOBAL:removeListBox.SelectedItems.Count
            $removeButton.Text = "Remove $numberOfPackages packages ($Global:removeSize GB)"
            $removeButton.IsEnabled = $true
         }
      }
      $loadListBox.Clear()
   } else {
      $Global:removeSize = 0
      $numberOfPackages = 0
      $removeButton.Text = "Remove $numberOfPackages packages ($Global:removeSize GB)"
      $removeButton.IsEnabled = $false
   }
}
#___ Main Program ___
$Global:removeFolder = $Global:mainFolder
$destinationDrive = $removeFolder.Substring(0,1)
$Global:freeSpace = (get-psdrive $destinationDrive).free
$freeSpaceGB = ($Global:freeSpace / 1gb).ToString('0')

#load main window
$mainWindow = getXamlgui -xamlName "databaseUpdateGUI.xml"

#----- Find all the goodies -----#
#Text windows
$loadPFtextBox = $mainWindow.FindName("loadSearchRtb")
$freeSpaceLabel = $mainWindow.FindName("freeSpaceLabel")
$removeListBox = $mainWindow.FindName("removePackagesBox")
$loadListBox= $mainWindow.FindName("selectPackagesBox")
$removePFtextBox = $mainWindow.FindName("removePFtextBox")
#Buttons
$searchButton = $mainWindow.FindName("browseButton")
$loadButton = $mainWindow.FindName("loadPackagesButton")
$removePackagesButton = $mainWindow.FindName("removePackagesButton")

#----- Set properties and actions -----#
$freeSpaceLabel.Content.Text = $freeSpaceGB + 'GB Free'
$loadListBox.SelectionMode = 'Extended'
$loadListBox.add_SelectionChanged($Function:loadSelectionChange)
$removeListBox.SelectionMode = 'Extended'
$removeListBox.add_SelectionChanged($Function:removeSelectionChange)
$removePFtextBox.Text = "$Global:removeFolder"
$searchButton.add_click($Function:loadBrowseButtonClick)
$loadButton.add_click($Function:loadButtonClick)
$removePackagesButton.add_click($Function:removeButtonClick)

#Load the form
$mainWindow.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

XML sheet. Note, styles taken out as code was too many characters

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Database Update Tool" 
        Height="600" 
        Width="1000"
        Background="Gainsboro"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
   <Grid Margin="2,2,12,2"
          Background="Gainsboro">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="380"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="499"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="499"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Begin adding Items-->
        <!-- Left Column -->
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Margin="10,0,10,0"
               Content="Load Folder Contents"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="16"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               FontFamily="Calibri">
        </Label>
        <Label Grid.Row="1"
               Margin="10,0,10,0"
               FontSize="14"
               FontWeight="DemiBold"
               Content="Select the location of loadable packages:"
               FontFamily="Calibri">
        </Label>
        <TextBlock x:Name="loadSearchRtb"
                     Grid.Row="2"
                   Background="White"
                     Margin="10,0,10,0" 
                     Width="400"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     FontSize="16">
        </TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Row="2"
                x:Name="browseButton"
                Margin="10,0,35,0"
                Content="..."
                Width="40"
                FontSize="14"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                Background="Gray">
        </Button>
        <Label Grid.Row="3"
               Margin="10,0,10,0"
               FontSize="14"
               FontWeight="DemiBold"
               Content="Select packages to load onto the system"
               FontFamily="Calibri">

        </Label>
        <ListBox x:Name="selectPackagesBox"
                   Background="White"
                   Grid.Row="4"
                   Margin="10,0,10,5" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        </ListBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="5"
                x:Name="loadPackagesButton"
                Content="Load 0 packages (0GB)"
                Width="225"
                Height="35"
                Margin="10,10,10,10"
                Background="ForestGreen"
                Foreground="White"
                FontFamily="Calibri"
                FontSize="16">
            
        </Button>
        <!-- Grid splitter (center column) -->
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.RowSpan="6" 
                      Width="2"
                      Background="Black"
                      IsEnabled="False">
        </GridSplitter>
        <!-- Right Column -->
        <Label Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Content="Destination Folder Contents"
               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="16"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               FontFamily="Calibri">
            
        </Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.Row="1"
               FontSize="14"
               FontWeight="DemiBold"
               Margin="10,0,10,0"
               Content="Location of packages:"
               FontFamily="Calibri">
        </Label>
        <TextBlock x:Name="removePFtextBox" 
                   Background="WhiteSmoke"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   FontFamily="Calibri"
                   FontSize="16"
                   FontWeight="DemiBold"
                   Margin="10,0,10,0" 
                   Width="250"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   IsEnabled="False">
        </TextBlock>
        <Label x:Name="freeSpaceLabel"
               Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.Row="2"
               Background="WhiteSmoke"
               Margin="280,0,0,0"
               Width="115"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                 <Run FontFamily="Calibri" 
                    FontWeight="Bold" 
                    FontSize="16" 
                    Text="">
                </Run>
        </Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="2"
               Grid.Row="3"
               Margin="10,0,10,0"
               FontSize="14"
               FontWeight="DemiBold"
               Content="Select packages to remove from the system"
               FontFamily="Calibri">
        </Label>
        <ListBox x:Name="removePackagesBox"
                   Background="White"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Grid.Row="4"
                   Margin="10,0,10,5">
        </ListBox>
        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="5"
                x:Name="removePackagesButton"
                Content="Remove 0 packages (0GB)"
                Width="225"
                Height="35"
                FontSize="16"
                Margin="10,10,10,10"
                Background="DarkRed"
                Foreground="White"
                FontFamily="Calibri">
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I you'd add a reproducible example for the WPF version, I'd give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, what @zett42 said, please provide a full sample

Comment: I edited my original question and provided the full code for powershell and the XML gui code. I am continuing to try, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you could create a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and link that here. Gist doesn't have a size limitation (AFAIK), so you can post the full XAML.

Comment: The style isn't necessary for the code to run, just looks better. Here is the link anyway. https://github.com/AngelOfChaos056/code/blob/main/databaseUpdateGUI.xml